# Antiderivative of a piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I solved this by integrating for both cases and writing my answer as a piecewise function. I think I am wrong because I may need to write it as a single function rather than a piecewise function since it asks for an antiderivative. Do I also need to use the 2nd fundamental theorem of calculus or is this not necessary ?

Also, since the function is not defined at $x=3$, is it okay to take the arbitrary constant as $0$ for both cases as continuity and differentiability isn't necessary at $x=3$?

Suppose that $h:(0,3) \cup (3,\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by

$
h(x):=
\begin{cases}
 x\sqrt{9-x^2}&\text{if}\, x\in (0,3)\\
 \sec^6(x)\tan^4(x)&\text{if}\, x\in(3,\pi)\\
\end{cases}
$

Find an antiderivative of $h$.

By integrating for both cases, my antiderivative is the function f:

$
f(x):=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{-1}{3}\sqrt{9-x^2}^\frac{3}{2}&\text{if}\, x\in (0,3)\\
 \ \frac{1}{9}\tan^{9}x+\frac{2}{7}\tan^{7}{x}+\frac{1}{5}\tan^{5}x&\text{if}\, x\in(3,\pi)\\
\end{cases}
$

This differentiates to $h$ so $f$ is an antiderivative of $h$. Can someone clear this up please ? :)

Comment: The antiderivative in the first case is wrong (there's an extra symbol). Beyond that, you can add any constant to either case of $f$ (they do not have to be the same) and the antiderivative would still be correct.

Comment: @user170231 I’ll fix that up, cheers. I was asking because the feedback said people lost marks because they didn’t write the solution as a single function. I don’t see how the anti derivative in the first case is incorrect - what extra symbol must I add ?

Comment: Remove, actually - the square root or the denominator in the exponent are superfluous. Only one is needed, either $\sqrt{9-x^2}^3$ (or rather $\sqrt{(9-x^2)^3}$) or $(9-x^2)^{3/2}$

Comment: @user170231 I am stupid! Thanks for telling me!