# How do I find the antiderivative of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How do I find the antiderivative of this function? I don't know where to start.[image: Question_image_link]

> Suppose that $h\colon (0,3)\cup(3,\pi)\to\mathbb R$ is given by $$h(x):=
> \begin{cases}
> x\sqrt{9-x^2}, &\text{if }x\in(0,3)\\
> \sec^6(x)\tan^4(x), &\text{if }x\in(3,\pi)
> \end{cases}$$
> Find an antiderivative of $h$, showing all of your calculations.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hint: integrate on separate intervals.

Comment: Behind the link provided by @user2661923 let me suggest also our guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [proving context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) and on how to [avoid "I don't know where to start" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). As you can see, posts like yours consisting of nothing but a bare problem statement quickly attract down votes and close votes.

Comment: See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611386/antiderivative-of-a-piecewise-defined-function#comment9719979_4611386) (actually the exact same exercise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, some hints:

- Substitute $\text{u}=9-x^2$:
  $$\int x\sqrt{9-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\int-\frac{\sqrt{\text{u}}}{2}\space\text{du}\tag1$$
- Use $\sec^2\left(x\right)=\tan^2\left(x\right)+1$ and substitute $\text{u}=\tan\left(x\right)$:
  $$\int\sec^6\left(x\right)\tan^4\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\text{u}^4\left(\text{u}^2+1\right)^2\space\text{du}\tag2$$

So:

$$\int\text{h}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\int x\sqrt{9-x^2}\space\text{d}x&\space\text{if}\space x\in\left(0,3\right)\\\\\displaystyle\int\sec^6\left(x\right)\tan^4\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x&\space\text{if}\space x\in\left(3,\pi\right)\end{cases}\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to make different cases for each.

$1)x∈(0,3):$

Since, $x∈(0,3)$ we can assume it to be $3\sin\theta$ for $\theta∈(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$,

Substituting gives,

$$\int\frac{27}{2}\sin\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta=-\int\frac{27}{2} \cos^2(\theta)d(\cos\theta)$$

By [Integration by parts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20and%20more%20generally,of%20their%20derivative%20and%20antiderivative) we have,

$$\int \sin\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta=-\int \cos^2(\theta)d(\cos\theta)=\cos^3\theta+\int \cos\theta d(\cos^2\theta)=\cos^3\theta +2 \int \sin\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta$$.

So, $$\int \sin\theta \cos^2\theta d\theta=-\frac{\cos^3(\theta)}{3}$$

So the antiderivative will be like, *$\frac{9\cos^3\theta}{2}+c$*. Where $x=3\sin\theta$

I know it's a long method then listed above but you should know as much alternatives you could know. This might increase your knowledge.

Hint to the 2nd part is already given as I see. I had a different solution for the 1st part so I posted. Hope you got it.